# How to get a DataGridView with vertical Columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my `Winform` `C#` application I have a `DataGridView`  that  bound with `DataTable` and have many records. 
I want to display details of  the selected row (of  `DataGridView` ) in the following Format (see Image).What `Control` or (Trick) should I use to achieve this.

[image]

**In other words:** “First Column of the Table should have Columns name and 2nd Column should have its corresponding values”

Comment: A ListView would probably be best for this.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman-Ok. will try with listview

Comment: You can try SQL Pivot to generate this kind of result from query level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, I wouldn't do this in a **DataGridView**, its really intended to display multiple records and you only want to display one record at a time.   I can suggest two alternate ways of dealing with this:

The typical approach if you know the fields to be displayed ahead of time would be to lay out a set of individual value displaying labels and other simple controls at design time.   This has the following advantages:

- The position of things is more flexible
- The type of control used for each individual field can be customized.   For example, a booean value might display with a check box, rather than with text.
- The labels preceding the value can be localized into the users language.   Even if not an international application, its sometimes useful to display labels that are different from the database schema names of the columns.

If you don't know the fields to be displayed at design time, or don't want to bother laying them out, use a **PropertyGrid** control instead of a **DataGridView**.   I've never actually tried this with a DataTable as a data source, but it looks like there is a well developed answer for that at [C#/winforms: how to best bind a propertygrid and a System.Data.DataRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943621/c-winforms-how-to-best-bind-a-propertygrid-and-a-system-data-datarow)

Answer (score 3):

I hope you 'll try to use PIVOT  in sql to make your dataset looks like the above result. Instead of that you can pivot (switch rows and columns) in your DataSet and bind that dataset to your grid.
See below link,It'll help you..

http://codemaverick.blogspot.com/2008/02/transpose-datagrid-or-gridview-by.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do to achieve this

1. Once the main DataGridView is built and databound, iterate through the collection of Columns on the grid and store the names of visible columns in a List (do this only once)
2. Create another simple DataGridView based control (do this only once)
3. Create a SelectionChanged event handler and get the Index of selected row, you can get it by dg.SelectedRows[0].Index if using single row selection mode.
4. Create a DataTable with two columns, one Field and the other Value. Iterate through the built list of required columns in step 1 and add the column name in field and populate the Value by retrieving DataRow from the master datatable bound to the main DataGridView using the Index obtained in step 3.
5. Clear the control created in step 2, bind it to the datatable created in step 4 and show.

Answer (score 0):

The `Visual Basic Power Packs` has a `DataRepeater` control which can be used in these situations. You can design each row the way you want to and place whatever controls you want to place in it, for each row.

Here is a video demonstrating how this DataRepeater control may be used:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/funkyonex/The-New-DataRepeater-Control-in-the-Latest-Power-Packs-Release

You can download the visual basic power packs:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=25169

Also, read this if you are using Visual Studio 2013:

http://ntcoder.com/bab/2013/12/20/visualbasic-powerpack-missing-from-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 0):

```
                   string[] C = new string[50];// For column Name
                    DataTable dt1;//Put your Table data in dt1

                    for (int r = 0; r < dt1.Columns.Count; r++)
                    {
                        C[r] = dt1.Columns[r].ToString();
                    }

                    for (int r = 0; r < dt1.Columns.Count; r++)
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(C[r], dt1.Rows[0][C[r]].ToString());

                    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>Reg_no</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblreg_no" Text='<%# Eval("reg_no") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblname" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbldob" Text='<%# Eval("dob") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in your code behind, you just bind it like another container.

```
Repeater1.datasource= "";
Repeater1.DataBind();
```