# how do I direct my datagrid query vertically

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

So, I'm working in c# and I'm trying to get my text displayed vertically in a datagrid. I'm using this code to show my data

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select P41A, P41B, P41D, P41E, P41F, P41G, P41H, P41I, P41J FROM H41RD h;", conectar);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dvg.DataSource = dt;
        DataGrid d = new DataGrid();
```

and it shows like this:
[image]

but what I want is this:

[image]

so I don't know if I need to change my query in workbench or if I should add something to my datagrid, because the only thing that I want is to change the orientation soooo... ;C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a DataGridView with vertical Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320975/how-to-get-a-datagridview-with-vertical-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ swap columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950495/linq-swap-columns-into-rows)