# Create custom object list collection in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, list, json.net, propertygrid

By default when you use the following:

```
List<myClass> l = new List<myClass>();
```

This will show the collection editor and with each item that you add it will show the properties of that class.

Because I am pulling data from a JSON file I need to work around this and not create the class, lets say my JSON file is the following:

```
{
    "name": "Pages",
    "type": "collection",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "Text",
            "value": "page1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Name",
            "value": "page1"
        },
        {
            "name": "BackgroundColor",
            "value": "black"
        }           
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "Text": "page1",
            "Name": "page1",
            "BackgroundColor": "black"
        },
        {
            "Text": "page2",
            "Name": "page2",
            "BackgroundColor": "blue"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure on how to do this without creating a class, any help would be appreciated.

My guess is somehow dynamically create a class based on the JSON file and then somehow create a list from that.

I have been trying to come up with a solution for days but couldn't work a way around it.

Another idea I had was to create an object list as follows:

```
List<object> l = new List<object>();
```

and then somehow modify the "Add" button event in the collection editor to display custom properties.

Comment: Can you transform this to `DataTable`? If so you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/943713/2530848)

Comment: I understand that you can use this to populate a property grid but what about the collection editor property grid? http://i.imgur.com/8YC6Q4j.png

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What about that? What happens and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Well as you can see that I am using List<object> so in the collection editor you can see the properties of object, now is it possible to get lets say the table2 (view screenshot) to show in the collection editor properties? http://i.imgur.com/DuI7UHf.png